# Issue with Do while statent in Java

Tags: java, do-while

I need to calculate the velocity and position of an object until it reaches the ground.

I believe I have a handle on everything else except for the Do while statement (which I am required to use).
I just need a poke in the right direction or at least to be told why it is doing this:the user input should be greater than 600 or else the program is supposed to have the error message and request the user tries again until the correct value is put in.
My issue is that even if I choose 700, I receive the error message anyway when I should not. The HEIGHTTHRESHOLD is a public constant that is set to 600.
I didn't post my entire program since I only need pointers on this portion.

```
public static int  initialPosition() {
     Scanner keyboard= new Scanner (System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter the initial position (Must be over 600 feet)");
       int position = keyboard.nextInt();

       do {
             System.out.println("Error- Position is too low! Try Again");
             System.out.println("Enter the initial position "
                     + "(Must be over 600 feet)");
            keyboard.nextInt();
       break;

       }while (position>HEIGHTTHRESHOLD);
        return position;
}
```

Comment: ```do{...}while```; where the ```{...}``` block is executed _at least_ once.

Comment: SO pro-tip : do not disclose that you are asking for help on homework. Most of the "homework questions" are low-quality and yours might be aggregated with them, getting more downvotes than it should.

Comment: do not put the break in the middle of the do-while loop.  as written it is not a loop, since it will only "loop" one time.

Comment: I just wanted to thank everyone for their help! I think I have what I need now. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
if(position>HEIGHTTHRESHOLD){
do {
             System.out.println("Error- Position is too low! Try Again");
             System.out.println("Enter the initial position "
                     + "(Must be over 600 feet)");
            position = keyboard.nextInt();
       break;
}
       }while (position>HEIGHTTHRESHOLD);}
```

while would be much better in this case but if you need this...

Answer (score 0):

A `do{} while()` statement will execute the first time without even checking the condition. It will only not **repeat** if the condition is not met.

Simply use a `while(){}` statement.

If you assignment requires the use of a `do while` I would suggest:

```
boolean postiionEntered = false;
int position
do{

    position = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(position<HEIGHTTHRESHOLD){

        System.out.println("Error- Position is too low! Try Again");
        System.out.println("Enter the initial position "      
        + "(Must be over 600 feet)");
    else{positionEntered = true;}
}
while(positionEntered == false)
return position;
```

Hope this helps,

Liam

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading the Oracle java tutorial (focus on [this tutorial trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html)).

```
do
{
    ... blah
    position = keyboard.nextInt();
} while (position < 601)
// pay attention! you continue asking for input only while the input is
// less-than the minimum
```

Answer (score 0):

As Liam said, do while loops are executed at least once. So, you need to make sure you run through your entire logic and see what will happen the 1st time as well as each N time.
Avoid using "break" and other "get out of my loop" statement unless you really really have to.

Something like this seem better in my book:

```
public static int  initialPosition() {
 Scanner keyboard= new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter the initial position (Must be over 600 feet)");

   do {
         int position = keyboard.nextInt();
         if (position < HEIGHTTHRESHOLD) {
             System.out.println("Error- Position is too low! Try Again");
             System.out.println("Enter the initial position "
                 + "(Must be over 600 feet)");
         }

   }while (position<HEIGHTTHRESHOLD);
    return position;
```

}

Comment: You are freaking awesome! That worked! Thank you so much!